# Is there a Benefit to Having the Name of Javascript Functions Start with Lowercase Letters?

Tags: javascript, naming-conventions

I have noticed that most Javascript methods (framework and custom) start with lowercase letters.  Is there a reason and/or benefit to this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1564398/javascript-method-naming-lowercase-vs-uppercase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no technical reason.  It's about readability, tradition, similarity to existing code. Consistency leads to readability, and arbitrary divergence stands out for no good reason.

Comment: Additionaly, the convention is to start constructor functions with an uppercase letter. This mirrors the conventions in Java and other OO langauges.

Comment: I'm not knocking your answer, but if I play devil's advocate I might say that mixed case for the first letter of the words that make up a method name makes for more difficult readability.  Also, working without source control is a bad tradition many still follow, but that doesn't make it good to follow.  If most existing code for a platform is poorly formed, why emulate it?

Comment: Obviously, diverging from norm when there's a good reason to do so is a *very* good thing. But capitalization is pretty subjective, so absent a compelling benefit (other than personal preference), why add gratuitous differences?

Answer (score 0):

In any case-sensitive language, it's especially important to be consistent about how you case variables. But starting with lower-vs-upper is just an idiom that's evolved in the community.