# javascript declaring variable issue

Tags: javascript

I'am doing somtehing like this

```
Client.Selectors = {
    var cfg = null;
    Init:function(config){
       ...
       cfg = config;
       ...
    },
    Close:function(){
    }
};
```

And on the debugger of chrome I got this error :

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

I don't know why

Comment: Be careful with the notation, in javascript a capitalized variable is a constructor. If you're not declaring a constructor you should use camelCase with the first letter in lowercase.

Comment: @Nicosunshine That's only a convention and not a language feature. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1564398/javascript-method-naming-lowercase-vs-uppercase

Comment: @Phil that was what I ment :), didn't realize that sounded like a language feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have problem here:

```
var cfg = null;
```

Should be:

```
cfg : null,
```

Since you are using *object literal* notation. So `=` changed to `:` and `;` changed to `,`.

```
Client.Selectors = {
    cfg : null,
    Init:function(config){
       this.cfg = config;
    },
    Close:function(){
    }
};
```

**Learn More:**

- [JavaScript Object Literal](http://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/obj_lit.php)

Answer (score 3):

```
var cfg = null;
Client.Selectors = {
    Init:function(config){
       ...
       cfg = config;
       ...
    },
    Close:function(){
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring Selectors with the object literal notation and as such the syntax is

```
some = {
    identifier:value,
    id2:function() {}
}
```

and all the properties are accessible from the outside.... you may want to consider using a constructor function to encapsulate your cfg

```
some = function() {
   var privateVar = "something";

   return {
      init: function() {
         alert(privateVar);
      }
   }

}
```