# How do I correctly call a functions of anonymous function in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance, anonymous-function

Here is my code:

```
var A = (function(){
    "use strict";

    function FetchJSON(){
        return someValue;
    }

    var Class = function(){
        // how do I correctly call FetchJSON() from inside this class definition?
    };

    return {
        Class: Class,
        fetchJson: FetchJSON
    };
})()
```

So basically I'm using JSLint to clean up my code and I'm just calling FetchJSON() from inside the Class object/function definition but JSLint is telling me I need to use the word 'new' before the FetchJSON() call and I'm thinking I don't. The code works with out the word 'new' just fine but JSLint is telling me it should have it. What's the deal?

Thanks

Comment: It's probably because the first letter of `FetchJSON` is capitalized and JSLint thinks it's a constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call the function fetchJSON instead of FetchJSON, so JSLint does not think it's a constructor.

Answer (score 1):

By convention only functions that are intended to be used as constructors (ie with the `new` keyword) should begin with capital letters - see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1564398/javascript-method-naming-lowercase-vs-uppercase) for more detail.

Answer (score 1):

It's because the first letter of `FetchJSON` is capitalized, causing JSLint to interpret it as a constructor. If you wish to keep it capitalized despite the warning, you may.