# Match a specific property between two object arrays and insert a value then to one object

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two object arrays like -

```
var arrayOne = [{"Content":1, "ValueContent":2},{"Content":3, "ValueContent":4}]
var arrayTwo = [{"Ex": "x", "ValueNum":20,"Content_Key":3}, {"Ex":"y","ValueNum":10,"Content_Key": 1}]
```

I want to match `Content` value from `arrayOne` to `Content_Key` value in `arrayTwo`. If its a match the update `arrayTwo` with `ValueContent` from `arrayOne`. So the updated array would look like -

```
 var arrayTwo = [{"Ex": "x", "ValueNum":20,"Content_Key":3, "ValueContent":4}, {"Ex":"y","ValueNum":10,"Content_Key": 1, "ValueContent":2}]
```

Any leads on how to do this? Currently i am able to the matching part but beyond that am stuck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Performance is optimised if you use some kind of hash for this. As others have shown you can create an object for this, but here is a solution with an ES6 `Map`, which is passed as the `thisArg` to `forEach`:

```
arrayTwo.forEach(function (el) {
    el.ValueContent = this.get(el.Content_Key);
}, new Map(arrayOne.map(el => [el.Content, el.ValueContent])));
```

```js
var arrayOne = [{"Content":1, "ValueContent":2},{"Content":3, "ValueContent":4}];
var arrayTwo = [{"Ex": "x", "ValueNum":20,"Content_Key":3}, {"Ex":"y","ValueNum":10,"Content_Key": 1}];

arrayTwo.forEach(function (el) {
    el.ValueContent = this.get(el.Content_Key);
}, new Map(arrayOne.map(el => [el.Content, el.ValueContent])));

console.log(arrayTwo);
```

#### Remark

You use property names that have the first character capitalised. You might want to consider starting with a lowercase letter for these, as there is [a convention](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1564489/5459839) to reserve the initial uppercases for names of constructors (or classes in ES6).

Comment: I thought that convention is for variables, not properties of plain objects. It would make objects a lot less useful otherwise, since often times you don't exactly know what data would go in them as it might be coming in from JSON or maybe user input or something.

Comment: @vlas, properties can also be constructors, so it would make sense to apply the convention throughout. You'll notice that the syntax highlighter of StackOverflow also applies a different color for such properties. Of course, if you have constraints in your source data, then you should just ignore this convention ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a hash table for `arrayOne` and apply `ValueContent` to the appropriate object if exist.

```js
var arrayOne = [{ "Content": 1, "ValueContent": 2 }, { "Content": 3, "ValueContent": 4 }],
    arrayTwo = [{ "Ex": "x", "ValueNum": 20, "Content_Key": 3 }, { "Ex": "y", "ValueNum": 10, "Content_Key": 1 }],
    hash = Object.create(null);

arrayOne.forEach(function (a) {
    hash[a.Content] = a;
});

arrayTwo.forEach(function (a) {
    if (hash[a.Content_Key]) {
        a.ValueContent = hash[a.Content_Key].ValueContent;
    }
});

console.log(arrayTwo);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

First I would create an index of objects within `arrayTwo` where the key would be the `Content_Key`. That is, I would build an object where properties are `Content_Key` and values the objects within the whole array.

Thus, I can locate objects by `Content_Key` easily.

Finally, I would iterate each item in `arrayOne` to add `ValueContent` property to them using the whole object index:

```js
var arrayOne = [{"Content":1, "ValueContent":2},{"Content":3, "ValueContent":4}];
var arrayTwo = [{"Ex": "x", "ValueNum":20,"Content_Key":3}, {"Ex":"y","ValueNum":10,"Content_Key": 1}];

var arrayTwoIndex = arrayTwo.reduce(function(result, item) {
  result[item.Content_Key] = item;
  
  return result;
}, {});

arrayOne.forEach(function(item) {
   // This approach of using an object index is very powerful because
   // otherwise you would need to iterate arrayTwo for each arrayOne
   // iteration, and this way you save a lot of CPU cycles because 
   // you're directly accessing to arrayTwo objects by Content_Key!
   arrayTwoIndex[item.Content].ValueContent = item.ValueContent;
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(arrayTwo));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple approach (reduces the complexity to `O(n+m)` where `n` is number of items in `arrayOne` and `m` is number of items in `arrayTwo`)

```js
var arrayOne = [{"Content":1, "ValueContent":2},{"Content":3, "ValueContent":4}];
var arrayTwo = [{"Ex": "x", "ValueNum":20,"Content_Key":3}, {"Ex":"y","ValueNum":10,"Content_Key": 1}];

//prepare map from arrayone for Content value
var map = {};
arrayOne.forEach( function( item ){
  map[ item[ "Content" ] ] = item[ "ValueContent" ];
});

//Now iterate arrayTwo to see if there is a match
arrayTwo = arrayTwo.map( function( item ){
  var contentKey = item[ "Content_Key" ];
  if ( map[ contentKey ] != undefined )
  {
      item[ "ValueContent" ] = map[ contentKey ];
  }
  return item;
});

console.log( arrayTwo );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use 2 forEach methods

```
arrayTwo.forEach(obj2 => { arrayOne.forEach(obj1 => {
if (obj2.Content_Key === obj1.Content)  obj2.ValueContent = obj1.ValueContent;
})});
console.log(arrayTwo); //[ { Ex: 'x', ValueNum: 20, Content_Key: 3, ValueContent: 4 }, { Ex: 'y', ValueNum: 10, Content_Key: 1, ValueContent: 2 } ]
```