# Different ways of defining Constructor function

Tags: javascript, jquery, constructor

So being new to javascript and jQuery I have come across two ways in which a constructor function is defined.

First something like this. Presumably simple javascript constructor function

```js
var assigner = function assigner(object){
  this.title = object.title;
  this.message = object.message;
  this.backGround = object.svgBackground;
  this.content = object.content;
  this.id = '#' + object.title;
  
  var className = "projects-title";
  var tagName = "p";
  $(this.id).append("<" + tagName + " class = " + className + "></" + tagName + ">");
  
  var className = "projects-message";
  var tagName = "p";
  $(this.id).append("<" + tagName + " class = " + className + "></" + tagName + ">");
  
  var className = "projects-background";
  var tagName = "p";
  $(this.id).append("<" + tagName + " class = " + className + "></" + tagName + ">");
  
  var className = "projects-content";
  var tagName = "p";
  $(this.id).append("<" + tagName + " class = " + className + "></" + tagName + ">");
  $(this.id).find('.projects-title').append(this.title);
  $(this.id).find('.projects-message').append(this.message);
  $(this.id).find('.projects-background').append(this.backGround);
  $(this.id).find('.projects-content').append(this.content);
};
```

Then Second. Essentially a jQuery constructor function.

```js
(function( $ ){
$.fn.methodToCreate= function(tagName,className,id) {
  $(id).append("<"+tagName+" "+"class="+"\'"+className+"\'>"+"SampleContent"+"</"+tagName+">");
  return this;
}; 
})( jQuery );
```

I was hoping if someone can explain as to why do we require this special syntax in the second function. One thing I have come across quite frequently is people saying it "extends" jQuery. Are there any resources where a newbie can wrap his head around this phenomenon?

Comment: The second isn't really a constructor function: you wouldn't call it with `new`. And adding a jQuery method that doesn't use `this` (other than to return it) doesn't really make sense, because the whole point of jQuery methods is that they operate on the jQuery object they were called on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first example you provided can be used as a constructor, but convention dictates that we capitalize constructor method names to clarify that distinction (see here for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1564489). Here is a simple example of a `Book` constructor:

```
function Book(name, year) {
  this.name = name;
  this.year = '(' + year + ')';
};
```

You can also assign it to a variable:

```
var Book = function(name, year) {
  this.name = name;
  this.year = '(' + year + ')';
};
```

In this example, this constructor can be used to create `Book` instances, like so:

```
var hamlet = new Book('Hamlet', 1603);
```

The second example you provided is not what I'd call a constructor method, but rather a jQuery *plugin*. It will *extend* the jQuery instance, by attaching a new method to it, to allow you to call the method in one of your JS files like so:

```
$('someSelector').methodToCreate('div', '.someClass', '#someId');
```

An immediately-invoked function expression is used in the example you gave, for encapsulation and to protect the `$` instance. You can learn more about how to create jQuery plugins here: https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/

Answer (score 0):

Use the es6 class syntax

```
class MyGreatClass {

  constructor(){

  }

}
```

Comment: "I was hoping if someone can explain as to why do we require this special syntax in the second function."